# Unusual tremolo on guitar with overdrive

Tags: electric-guitar, electronics, vibrato, wiring

was looking for some help on a somewhat weird issue im having. I just installed new pots, caps, and humbuckers in a guitar. When you crank the overdrive, it has an extremely aggressive tremolo that increases with the sustain speeding up like if you push an effect pedal down. Recently I did use some deoxit on the pots due to some corrosion. I did it yesterday, so assumingely had an impact. I didnt test the same level of overdrive before using the deoxit, so could be something else for all I know. I was hoping to confirm whether this may’ve caused the issue or not, and if its something id have to replace the pots for. Thanks.

Edit: 13.7k bridge output, 7.7k neck output, if that somehow helps

Comment: It seems weird that an overdrive pedal would add vibrato. Can you post an audio example?

Comment: It’s definitely coming from the guitar. Been swapping out amps and other guitars and nothing like that happens. Ill see what i can do for an audio sample, but not too familiar with doing it so might take a bit

Comment: Is it actual vibrato [pitch changing] or is it tremolo [volume changing] or is it just beating [two notes very slightly out of tune & "arguing"] ?

Comment: Yea it was tremolo, very sorry about that. Definitely fits as volume drastically changing

Comment: Does it speed up on a single note or chord, or increase with changes in pitch or other variables.

Comment: It's possible you've got a "tank circuit" in your new components which acts as a local oscillator going in and out of resonance with the notes.  I agree that some sound samples might help with the diagnosis.